# Как сделать текст в background по середине и по вертикали и по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css

Вот дан прямоугольник, а текст прямо по середине и по вертикали и по горизонтали. Не подскажите как так сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.row{
width: 100%;
font-family: calibri;
background-color: #blue;
text-align: center;
color: white;
height: 100px;
margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

<div class="row">
<h1>Текст</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много способов, например так:

```css
.row{
  width: 100%;
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>Текст</h1>
</div>
```

А вообще в гугле наберите `css vertical align` и найдёте кучу примеров.

Comment: благодарю за помощь